# Trying to instantiate geoprocessor with .Net vs 2010

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5374EC4C-1AA2-4829-A811-DE624ECEC23F} failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)).

```
GeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessor(); 
gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", PICKSIMPORT); 
IGpEnumList gdbs = gp.ListWorkspaces("", ""); 
string gdb = gdbs.Next(); 
while (gdb != "") { Console.WriteLine(gdb.ToString());
 gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", gdb); 
IGpEnumList fcs = gp.ListFeatureClasses("", "", ""); 
string fc = fcs.Next(); 
while (fc != "") { Console.WriteLine(fc.ToString()); 
fc = fcs.Next();
gdb = gdbs.Next();
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that leads to this error?

Comment: Have you initialized your Arc license?

Comment: This forum post may help: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=263376

Comment: Here is the code. it errors out on the first line.

Comment: Here is the code. it errors on the first line. GeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessor(); gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", PICKSIMPORT); IGpEnumList gdbs = gp.ListWorkspaces("", ""); string gdb = gdbs.Next(); while (gdb != "") { Console.WriteLine(gdb.ToString()); gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", gdb); IGpEnumList fcs = gp.ListFeatureClasses("", "", ""); string fc = fcs.Next(); while (fc != "") { Console.WriteLine(fc.ToString()); fc = fcs.Next(); } gdb = gdbs.Next(); }

Comment: This belongs in the question itself not as an answer. You can edit your original question to add this information and then delete this answer.

Comment: Which ArcGIS references have you added to your project?

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar error message within the same context.  First, I added a reference (in Solution Explorer, right-click 'References', select 'Add Reference') to the ESRI.ArcGIS.Version assembly.

Then I added the following line before the creation of your geoprocessor object:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
```

From:  http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/12/01/migrating-to-engine-9-4-and-using-the-versionmanager/